# Metric-space complete?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces, lp-spaces

My question is if a specific metric-space is complete, respectively under which conditions it is complete. I am rather a newby, but hope that the question is understandable.

The metric-space is defined by the set of initial conditions of a system of ordinary differential equations, and a distance measure with respect to their solutions.

Let $\frac{d}{dt}z=f(z,t)$, $z\in\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, be a system of ordinary differential equations, with $f$ continuous in $z$ and $t$. Assume that for every initial condition $z(0)=\bar{z}\in\bar{\mathbb{Z}}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a unique and continuous in time solution denoted by $\zeta(t,\bar{z})$ for $t\in\left[0,\infty\right)$.

Given this system of ODEs, I defined the metric-space $(\bar{\mathbb{Z}}, d)$, with $d$ given by
$$d(\bar{z}_1,\bar{z}_2)=\int_0^\infty w(t)\left|h(\zeta(t,\bar{z}_1))-h(\zeta(t,\bar{z}_2))\right|^p dt.$$ 
Here, $h:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is some continuous function, $p\in\left[1,\infty\right)$ and $w:\left[0,\infty\right)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ some weight. Assume that for every $\bar{z}_1,\bar{z}_2\in\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ it is given that $0\leq d(\bar{z}_1,\bar{z}_2)<\infty$, and $d(\bar{z}_1,\bar{z}_2)=0\Rightarrow \bar{z}_1=\bar{z}_2$.

I would like to prove that if $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a closed sub-space of the Euclidean space, $(\bar{\mathbb{Z}}, d)$ is complete.

I tried to prove this by picking some (fixed) $\hat{z}\in\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ and by defining another space $(K,d_k)$, with $K=\{k:\left[0,\infty\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:k(t)=h(\zeta(t,\bar{z}))-h(\zeta(t,\hat{z})),\bar{z}\in\bar{\mathbb{Z}}\}$, and $d_k(k_1,k_2)=\|k_1-k_2\|_{L_p}^p$ defined by
$$\|k_1-k_2\|_{L_p}^p=\int_0^\infty w(t)|k_1(t)-k_2(t)|^pdt.$$
Intuitively, I would guess that $(\bar{\mathbb{Z}}, d)$ is complete if $(K, d_k)$ is complete. Since $(K, d_k)$ is a subspace of the w-weighted $L_p$ space which is complete, I "only" would have to show that $(K,d_k)$ is closed. However, here I got lost...

Is $(\bar{\mathbb{Z}}, d)$ complete for $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ being a closed sub-space of the Euclidean space, and, if not, are there some ``mild'' assumptions I could make such that it is complete (I know, mild is not well defined...)?

Comment: I take that $\mathbb Z$ isn't the set of integers, right? That's quite irritating.

Comment: Yes,$ \mathbb {Z} $ is just some subspace of $\mathbb {R }^n $, e.g. defined by some inequality constraints. Sorry for the confusion, I took it over from some publication in which it was proper defined and didn't remember to change it...

Comment: I think people get the right idea from the context. but no need to make things more confusing than necessary :)

Comment: Any closed subsets of complete metric space is complete

Comment: @Mohammad: I got that any closed subset of a complete metric space is complete. But: why (or when) is $(K, d_k) $ a closed subset of Lp (if this is what you referred to)? Might be trivial, but currently not for me...

Comment: Indeed, the set $\mathbb{K}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ which in turns a closed subset of the space of continuous function (which complete space).

Comment: Hm, no, still don't get it. $K$ is a subset of w-weighted $L_p$-space, and $\mathbb{Z}$ (careful: not the set of integers) is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I don't get the meaning of "K is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$", and also not the rest.

Comment: To clarify where I struggle: my idea was to show 

(i) $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ closed subset of Euclidean space $\Rightarrow$ $(K,d_k)$ closed.

(ii) $(K,d_k)$ closed and subset of $L_p$ (which is complete) $\Rightarrow$  $(K,d_k)$ complete.

(iii) $(K,d_k)$ complete $\Rightarrow$ $(\bar{\mathbb{Z}},d)$ complete.

Step (ii) is trivial, but I don't know how to prove (i) & (iii)...